# Google Tag Manager Macro Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have a GTM tag that listens for linkClinks that end with '.zip'. I'd like to filter everything out of the path EXCEPT the filename 'MyFile.zip'

**Tag Name:** Track Zip Downloads

**Tag Type:** Universal Analytics

**Track Type:** Event

**Category:** Button

**Action:** Download

**Label:** {{ element url }}

**Firing Rules:**

1. {{event}} equals 'gtm.linkClick'
2. {{element url}} ends with '.zip'

When I click a link currently, the Label is 'http://mydomain.com/zips/MyFile.zip. How can I filter out the 'http://mydomain.com/zips/' part of the URL?

Answer (score 0):

A regex to extract the last part of the URL would be ie. the file name:

```
(?<=/)(.(?<!/))*$
```

This would select anything following the last forward slash. I hope it helps.